# Best resource for learning and seeing examples of Behavior Driven Development (BDD)

Tags: domain-driven-design, behavior

I am trying to creating Cucumber/Gerkin BDD Feature and Scenario descriptions, and am seeking examples just at the domain specific language.  In particular, examples and suggestions to make sure I cam covering corner conditions, clear examples so we are following best practices and approaches, to make sure both developers and BA's are putting together specifications that make most sense and are easily understood as we bring on new folks based on a set of learning materials (e.g. books or websites).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might start [here](http://cukes.info/) and [here](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/cucumber-introduction/) for Cucumber.